# Intraday Historical Data: CME S&P 500 E-Mini Futures

Tags: market-data, historical-data

Where can you find ESZ22 (CME S&P 500 E-Mini Futures) prices going back multiple years? Ideally, I'm looking for bars every hour or more.

The same for CBOE VIX Futures.

Comment: No, because that does not actually tell me where to find CBOE VIX Futures in the specified format. None of the sources in that answer support simple CBOE futures.

Answer (score 4):

A few options:

- [CME DataMine](https://datamine.cmegroup.com/#/)
- [Databento](https://databento.com/portal/detail?type=dataSet&dataSetId=GLBX.MDP3)
- [Cboe Data Shop](https://datashop.cboe.com/cme-futures-trades)